# PROLOG Selecting only one answer of multiple possibilities

Tags: prolog

I have a code like this:

```
op:-
   keyword(a),
   write('Answer A'), nl.
op:-
   keyword(a),
   keyword(b),
   write('Answer A and B'), nl.
op:-
   keyword(a),
   keyword(b),
   keyword(c)
   write('Answer A, B and C'), nl.
```

Keywords provide details into the answer that must be used, problem is. I want the answer to be as specific as possible and provide only ONE. In this case, if I got both keyword a, b and c, I would get:

Answer A.

Answer A and B.

Answer A, B and C.

But what Id like to get is just:

Answer A, B and C.

¿How is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Found a workaround: Using "!" and ordering them from more informed to less informed.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way is to add negations of the conditions that do not apply:

```
op :-
  keyword(a),
  not keyword(b),
  not keyword(c),
  write('Answer A'), nl.
op :-
  keyword(a),
  keyword(b),
  not keyword(c),
  write('Answer A and B'), nl.
op :-
  keyword(a),
  keyword(b),
  keyword(c)
  write('Answer A, B and C'), nl.
```

or you can use if-then-else:

```
op :-
  keyword(a),
  ( keyword(b) ->
    ( keyword(c) ->
      write('Answer A, B and C'), nl
    ; write('Answer A and B'), nl )
  ; write('Answer A'), nl ).
```